# c++ win32api value encoding corrupted when returning

Tags: c++, winapi, encoding, callback

I hardly know how to describe this behaviour, so this might be a reason why I'm not able to find an answer on my own - I simply don't know how to name this issue. So please be patient if the title is missleading or the question is wrong in some manner, but here it comes

I have a class method where I open a file and get the filename:

```
OPENFILENAME GuiUtils::ChooseFileDialog(HWND hwnd)
{
    OPENFILENAME ofn;
    char szFile[260];
    ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));
    ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
    ofn.hwndOwner = hwnd;
    ofn.lpstrFile = (LPWSTR)szFile;
    ofn.lpstrFile[0] = '\0';
    ofn.nMaxFile = sizeof(szFile);
    ofn.nFilterIndex = 1;
    ofn.lpstrFileTitle = NULL;
    ofn.nMaxFileTitle = 0;
    ofn.lpstrFilter = TEXT("Text Files (*.txt)\0*.txt\0All Files (*.*)\0*.*\0");
    ofn.lpstrInitialDir = NULL;
    ofn.Flags = OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST;
    HANDLE hf;

    // Display the Open dialog box. 
    if (GetOpenFileName(&ofn) == TRUE)
    {
        hf = CreateFile(ofn.lpstrFile,
            GENERIC_READ,
            0,
            (LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES)NULL,
            OPEN_EXISTING,
            FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
            (HANDLE)NULL);
    }
    return ofn;
}
```

When I look at `ofn.lpstrFile` everything looks encoded correctly
[image]

When I move on with my debugger and jumping back to the calling function something gets messed up:

Calling class method:

```
INT_PTR CALLBACK FormCreator::Callback(HWND hwnd, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (Message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDCHOOSEFILE)
        {
            GuiUtils *guiUtils = new GuiUtils();
            OPENFILENAME ofn = guiUtils->ChooseFileDialog(hwnd);
            ORMFactory* db = new ORMFactory(); // value in debugger changes here
            AbstractORM* sqlite = db->GetORMProvider(TEXT("SQLITE"));
            this->databaseFileName = (wstring)ofn.lpstrFile;
        }
        break;

  return 0;
}
```

[image]

Can someone please let me know what wrong here with `ofn.lpstrFile` and how to fix this?

Thank you

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/76252/What-are-TCHAR-WCHAR-LPSTR-LPWSTR-LPCTSTR-etc

Comment: You lied to the compiler here, `(LPWSTR)szFile`, and the reaped the inevitable consequence of that lie. Don't lie to the compiler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using the Unicode version of `GetOpenFileName()`, but you are giving it an ANSI buffer to store the selected filename in.  You are typecasting the buffer when assigning it to the `lpstrFile` field, hiding a compiler error that would have alerted you to this mismatch.

You need to change your buffer from `char` to `wchar_t` and get rid of the typecast.

However, even when you fix that, you have other errors in your code.

You are returning the populated `OPENFILENAME` to the caller, but it is still pointing at the local buffer that goes out of scope when `ChooseFileDialog()` exits.  So when the caller accesses the `lpstrFile` field, it is invoking *undefined behavior*.

`ChooseFileDialog()` is leaking a file handle each time `GetOpenFileName()` succeeds. You are not doing anything with the file handle, and you are not closing it. As such, you should not be opening the file at all

And you are leaking dynamically alloxated objects in your callback.

Try something more like this instead:

```
std::wstring GuiUtils::ChooseFileDialog(HWND hwnd)
{
    OPENFILENAMEW ofn;
    wchar_t szFile[MAX_PATH];
    ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));
    ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
    ofn.hwndOwner = hwnd;
    ofn.lpstrFile = szFile;
    ofn.lpstrFile[0] = '\0';
    ofn.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;
    ofn.nFilterIndex = 1;
    ofn.lpstrFileTitle = NULL;
    ofn.nMaxFileTitle = 0;
    ofn.lpstrFilter = L"Text Files (*.txt)\0*.txt\0All Files (*.*)\0*.*\0";
    ofn.lpstrInitialDir = NULL;
    ofn.Flags = OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST;
    HANDLE hf;

    // Display the Open dialog box. 
    if (!GetOpenFileNameW(&ofn))
        return L"";

    // what is this for???
    /*
    hf = CreateFileW(ofn.lpstrFile,
            GENERIC_READ,
            0,
            NULL,
            OPEN_EXISTING,
            FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
            NULL);
    */

    return ofn.lpstrFile;
}

INT_PTR CALLBACK FormCreator::Callback(HWND hwnd, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (Message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDCHOOSEFILE)
        {
            GuiUtils guiUtils;
            std::wstring fname = guiUtils.ChooseFileDialog(hwnd);
            if (fname.empty()) break;
            ORMFactory db;
            AbstractORM* sqlite = db.GetORMProvider(L"SQLITE");
            this->databaseFileName = fname;
        }
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for the detailed explanation and also for finding this error. at the end, could you please let me know what those signs are called I saw in the debugger, so that I will be able to better address my issues in the future?
I guess this was some kind of encoding issue then?

Comment: @abdoe this is not an encoding issue. It is a blatant misuse of the API. You are mismanaging memory and data types. The error shown in the screenshot of the caller is due to inspecting memory that is no longer valid.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a stack array `szFile` to store the file name. When your `ChooseFileDialog` method is finished, all stack variables are destroyed. Returning a pointer to the stack variable is undefined behavior.

This line is also strange:

```
ofn.lpstrFile = (LPWSTR)szFile;
```

You are casting a `char` array to a `wchar_t` pointer. If the filename is greater than 129 wide characters, you will get a buffer overflow.

To solve this problem, use dynamic memory allocation:

```
ofn.lpstrFile = new WCHAR[MAX_PATH];
ofn.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;
```

`Callback` will have to free the array when it is done using it:

```
delete[] ofn.lpstrFile;
```

Comment: Using dynamic memory will cause more problems then it solves in this example. This is not a good solution. Returning a `wstring` would be safer, and the function can continue using a stack-based array.